# Can't run my App on Android Studio cause by Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-constraintlayout, android-appwidget

this the error that I get :( what is the reason?

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sinagtala, PID: 24124
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sinagtala/com.example.sinagtala.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2505)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1462)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.sinagtala.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6093)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2458)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1462) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.example.sinagtala.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6093) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2458) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1462) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.sinagtala:drawable/mainmenu" (7f06008e)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f06008e a=-1 r=0x7f06008e}
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2602)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2538)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3738)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:498)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:494)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:490)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.<init>(ConstraintLayout.java:566)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.example.sinagtala.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6093) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2458) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1462) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)
```

Comment: Please, can you add xml code for more information. Providing only stack trace is not very helpful in this case

Answer (score 1):

As seen from tag from your question, I assume that you are trying to create and app widget layout using constraint layout. Unfortunately it's not possible. Please look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets#CreatingLayout)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. 
Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. [link-only-answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta4'
> ```

add above mentioned dependency in your (app gradle) and sync your gradle

Answer (score 0):

It says in your crash:
`Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.sinagtala:drawable/mainmenu" (7f06008e)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f06008e a=-1 r=0x7f06008e}`